# How to sync two planning entities to a value

Tags: drools, drools-planner

I want to sync planning values between two planning entities. In this case, I want to make two `SubjecTeacherPeriod` choose periods that "coincide" with each other, even though their possible value ranges are disjoint.

```
STP s1: period-N/A periodList->[1,2,3,4,5,6]
STP s2: period-N/A periodList->[106,107,108,109,110,111]
SyncConstraint(leftSTP = s1,rightSTP = s2)
<A rule for SyncConstraint that checks if s1.period and s2.period are compatible>
```

For example `Period`s `1` and `106` are compatible as they are both "first hours of Monday". Likewise for `2` and `107`.

I did set planning entity difficulty which assigns `s2` right after `s1` (I saw the log). But they are assigned values which are not compatible. And the system never recovers from such an error at the end of the solver action.

How can I make them sync?

---

Where I mentioned "compatible" and "coincide", I mean `Period`s which have two fields (day of week and day order) equal. Each class (and each `SubjectTeacherPeriod` whose possible periods in that class) has separate `Period`s.

Answer (score 1):

On the class `Period`, create a getter `getPeriodType()` (which returns "first hours on Monday" for example) and then add a score rule like this:

```
when
    MyEntity($leftType: period.periodType, $leftId : id, ...)
    MyEntity(period.periodType != $leftType, id < $leftId, ...)
```

Or if a `Period` can have multiple types, don't create that getter, but create a relation class `PeriodToPeriodTypeLink`:

```
when
    MyEntity($leftP : period, $leftId : id, ...)
    MyEntity($rightP : period, id != $leftId, ...)
    PeriodToPeriodTypeLink(period == $leftP, $t : type)
    not PeriodToPeriodTypeLink(period == $rightP, type == $t)
```